# "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement". Performing 2 SQL queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my SQL Server which contains columns

```
Currency, Amount, CurrencyRequestedTotal, Pcs
```

The table looks like this:

```
ID  Currency     Amount     Pcs         CurrencyRequestedTotal
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   USD          50000.00   4           NULL
2   NGN          30000.00   5           NULL
3   USD          49800.00   6           NULL
4   NGN          2500.00    6           NULL
```

I have these 2 SQL queries I wrote so far, one is to do the calculation and the second one is then to update the table with the ID using the Update query

It looks like this :

```
SELECT
    Currency, SUM(Amount) 
FROM
    [dbo].[CurrencyStats_SMO] 
WHERE
    Currency = 'NGN' 
GROUP BY 
    Currency

UPDATE [dbo].[CurrencyStats_SMO] 
SET CurrencyRequestedTotal = SUM(Amount) 
WHERE ID = 1
```

On the console, it does not show anything that looks like errors, but on the second note I get this

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Like what exactly do I appear to be missing?

Comment: What results do you want?  Do you want the USD rows updated with the value for the NGN currency, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports window functions and updatable CTEs.  I would recommend:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cs.*,
             sum(case when Currency = 'NGN' then amount end) over (partition by id) as sum_amount        
      from CurrencyStats_SMO cs
      where id = 1
    )
update toupdate
    set CurrencyRequestedTotal = sum_amount;
```

The above sets the total for *all* currencies to the same value.  If you want each currency to have its own total, then the query would look like:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cs.*,
             sum(amount) over (partition by id, currency) as sum_amount        
      from CurrencyStats_SMO cs
      where id = 1
    )
update toupdate
    set CurrencyRequestedTotal = sum_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subquery :

```
update smo
       set smo.CurrencyRequestedTotal = (select sum(smo1.Amount) 
                                         from [dbo].[CurrencyStats_SMO] smo1
                                         where smo1.Currency = smo.Currency
                                        )
from [dbo].[CurrencyStats_SMO] smo
where smo.Currency = 'NGN';
```

Comment: I changed sum(smo1.CurrencyRequestedTotal) to sum(smo1.Amount) and it works, now what if I want to update to ID, as shown above, Pls I do i do that??

Comment: @Hamed. . . If you want to update amount to specific `id` then change to `where` clause & change in `sub query`